# Is there a way to treat scala value as constant from java

Tags: java, scala, constants

I want to define a value in my Scala code and treat this value as constant (used in annotation) within my Java code (which is calling scala).

For example:

```
object MyValues {
   val a = 5
}
```

However when I'm trying to use this value within Java annotation it gives me an error: 
**java: attribute value must be constant**

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyJavaAnnotation {
   int aValue() default MyValues.a(); // <-- Error
}
```

Calling it like this doesn't work either: `MyValues$.MODULE$.a();`

I also tried to prefix the val with a ***final*** keyword without success.

Is there a workaround for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as far as I know. As a workaround, you can define a Java constant which calls the method:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyJavaAnnotation {
   int aValue() default A;
   static final int A = MyValues.a();
}
```

I *think* it could be defined inside the same annotation, if not move it somewhere.

Comment: Unfortunatly this gives the same error if defined in the annotation itself, since I can change the scala code (it's a module) I'll create a JAVA code that will hold the values and use it in scala and in my other java modules